# Can the elements of a two dimensional array be processed for some output in O(n) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o

Suppose that each row of an n*n array A consists of 1’s and 0’s such that, in any row of A, all the 1’s come before any 0’s in that row. Assuming A is already in memory, describe a method running in O(n) time for finding the row of A that contains the most 1’s.

Comment: And where are you thoughts? Could you elaborate at keast an approach with O(NlogN)?

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow is not an oracle where you ask questions and you receive wise answers.  Explain what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: This code is using single looping construct but executes while-block i*j times: 
#include<stdio.h>
int search(int mat[4][4]) {
int i = 0, j = 0,temp,highest,rowNo;
while ( i < 4 ){
    if ( mat[i][j] == 1) {
        temp++;
    }
    if(j<4){
        j++;
    }
    else {
        if(highest<temp){
            highest=temp;
            rowNo=i;
        }
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
}
printf("\n Row having highest no of 1's: %d", rowNo);
return 0; 
}
int main(){
 int mat[4][4] = { {0, 1, 1, 0},{0, 1, 0, 0},{1, 0, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1},};
 search(mat);
 return 0;
}

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: It is hard to read a code in comment.  Could you edit a question and add formatted code? (Or it is prohibited for novices?)

Comment: I am sure you will find the algotithm yourself if you think about the problem a bit. The key for finding the solution is the restriction that "all the 1’s come before any 0’s in that row". By the way, the matrix in your example does not seem to fulfill that restriction.

Answer (score 2):

1. start from `0`th row and scan from right to left to encounter the first 1
2. When you reach the `1`, update your answer. Suppose, the column is `j`.
3. Now for every row `i` from `1` to `n`, check if `j`th column holds 1.

   - If it holds `1`, that means there can be `1` in right too. So try to move right until finding the rightmost `1` and update the answer and `j`
   - If it holds 0, we won't need to go left or right as we have better result already from previous rows.

This algorithm will scan atmost `c * n` elements in total for all rows where `c` is some small constant. So time complexity is `O(n)`.

Moreover, You can use binary search to find the rightmost `1` for each row which will require less scan. At first, it seems binary search on each row will take `O(nlogn)`, but the left boundary will reduce in each row resulting fewer scan.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Minor nitpick: the total number of visited elements is not `n`, more like `3n` in the worst case (or `2n` if we look at column `j+1` instead of column `j`), e.g. on the matrix consisting of `1111....1110` rows. Other than that, great answer.

Comment: Hi @Gassa, I understood.Thanks and I've updated my answer in general.